# MVC Anonymous JSON returns incorrect boolean value?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, ravendb

I am working on implementing a full calendar with RavenDB.

I do a simple, as usual anonymous return of a model.

```
public JsonResult GetHolidays()
{
    return Json(Session.Query<Models.Holiday>().Select(d => new 
        { 
          id = d.Id, 
          title = d.Name, 
          start = d.DateStart, 
          end = d.DateEnd,
          allDay = true
        }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I set `allDay` to `true` but my result is `false`. (I point my broswer to the controller /Home/GetHolidays and that is the result string, I have done this many times before to make sure the JSON is correct)

```
[{"id":"holidays/97","title":"Piotr Test 2 - 1","start":"\/Date(1405284740420)\/","end":"\/Date(1405543940420)\/","allDay":false},{"id":"holidays/98","title":"Piotr Test 10 - 26","start":"\/Date(1404593542266)\/","end":"\/Date(1407703942266)\/","allDay":false},{"id":"holidays/99","title":"Piotr Test 3 - 0","start":"\/Date(1405198343713)\/","end":"\/Date(1405457543713)\/","allDay":false}]
```

[image]

I have done this so many times. Why is the result coming back as `false`?

Even if I set it to `false` it stays `false`. I cleared the cache and restarted a lot. Not sure why this is happening. Anybody knows what I am doing wrong?

Comment: How are you reading the `allDay` property? With Javascript? Is the key name incorrect - e.g. `response[0]['alllDay']` - such that you are getting an `undefined` value out, which is then interpreted as falsey?

Comment: Reading? I am just pointing my browser to the url `/Home/GetHolidays` and that's the string that comes back, with the value `false`. Oddly enough, I put in `"true"` and the value comes back `null` ? What the heck? Even if its the first property it makes no difference, the rest works.

Comment: For debugging purposes, store the result of your query in a local variable. Then put a breakpoint before you return the result as JSON. I'm wondering if the RavenDB query is the problem here. Does the `Select` method take a `Func<...>` or an `Expression<Func<...>>`?

Comment: What happens if you use  allDay = (Boolean)True

Comment: Ahh I figured it out! This is really weird!  Answer soon.

Comment: @Sparky - I tried that too. I thought maybe the parser was going nuts and casting to boolean would solve it.. but it was something else. I am new to RavenDB too anyway so I figured it must have been something to do with RavenDB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RavenDB doesn't provide a way to select user supplied values from the index.
Your query try to do a (trivially simple, but still) computation during the query, and RavenDB doesn't support that.
You can add that property after the query returns from RavenDB.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

Not completely sure how this influences the Anonymous type, but you **MUST** use `.ToList()` after query to RavenDB Session.

Its like the anonymous type originated/inherited from the model of the DB ... ? Not sure how to explain this behaviour.

```
public JsonResult GetHolidays()
{
    return Json(Session.Query<Models.Holiday>()**.ToList()**.Select(d => new 
        { 
          id = d.Id, 
          title = d.Name, 
          start = d.DateStart, 
          end = d.DateEnd,
          allDay = true
        }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

[image]

Comment: I hope somebody can give a nice technical answer. I will only accept  the answer that lets me know the truth :)

Comment: Looks like the RavenDB query provider has a bug. By calling ToList (or AsEnumerable) you transition to LINQ to objects which does not have bugs. You should report this bug.